# Center Wrap with Fixed Margins and Percentage Width. Is this Possible?

Tags: css

On a fluid site I am using a Wrap to center the content and its CSS is:

```
#Wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Is it possible to have a centered fluid wrap but with fixed margins in pixels?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: If it's in a container with a set width, yeah... What do yo mean by fluid? Window resize?

Comment: margin: 0 auto is to have a container in center position. If you remove margin: 0auto and give some fixed margins then how can you align it centrally for different window sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Apply `text-align:center;` on the parent element and `display:inline-block;` on the child element

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LueJQ/)**

```
<div class="outer" >
    <div id="Wrap"></div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.outer
{   
    background:yellow;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#Wrap {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
  background:pink;
  display:inline-block;

}
```